# Javascript function(parameter), assign parameter to var

Tags: javascript, jquery, function-parameter

i am failing and i don't understand why, i hope some body could help me out.

```
<div id="anvil" onmouseover="show(anvil_info)">
```

what i want to do is when you hover over anvil it starts a function

```
function show(x){
x.style.backgroundImage = "image_"+x
}
```

My idea was to use the assigned parameter when the function was called to get the image, but if i now look try to use it it doesn't work. How do i use a variable assigned to the function?

This one still doens't work:

```
function show(x, y){
    x.style.zIndex = "1";
    x.style.opacity = "1";
    y.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+ y + "_hover')"
}
<div id="anvil" onmouseover="show(anvil_info, 'anvil')"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new version :

```js
 function show(elem, pIdToChange){
   document.getElementById(pIdToChange).style.backgroundImage = "url('"+ pIdToChange + "_hover')";
   // with color switch
   document.getElementById(pIdToChange).style.color = "red";
   elem.style.color = "";
}
```

```html
<div id="anvil_info" onmouseover="show(this, 'anvil')" >Hello</div>
 <div id="anvil" onmouseover="show(this, 'anvil_info')">Goodbye</div>
```

---

The best is to use `onmouseover="show(this)"`

You'll get the element in your function, and then `x.style.backgroundImage` will work fine.

```js
function show(elem, pUrl){
  elem.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+ pUrl + "_hover')"
  alert(pUrl);
}
```

```html
<div id="anvil" onmouseover="show(this, 'anvil')">hello</div>
```

Comment: you need to use `this` ; take a look at my snippet, I've updated it

Comment: Now i have this problem, when he is getting the background this is what the call is: [object%20HTMLDivElement].jpg instead of "this".jpg

Answer (score -1):

```
function show(x, y, z){
    y.style.zIndex = "1";
    y.style.opacity = "1";
    x.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+ z + "_hover.jpg')"
}

 <div id="anvil_info" onmouseover="show(anvil, this, 'anvil')" onmouseout="hide(anvil, this, 'anvil')"></div>
 <div id="anvil" onmouseover="show(this, anvil_info, 'anvil')" onmouseout="hide(this, anvil_info, 'anvil')"></div>
```

works great, thanks to blag.

Comment: it's not how you use it XD I'll update my answer, I understand what you want now...